# Visual Studio Express 2010: Percentage Calculation (Calculator Function)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am in the process of creating a calculator for a school assignment. In it, I must include a percentage button where the first input (Num1) is the percentage, followed by the % button, then a second input (Num2) that we will calculate the percentage of, followed finally by the equals button.

So, for example, if I said *25 % 100 =* , I would want the value displayed to be *25 %*.

However, my values keep being returned by 0 % and I can't figure out how to code the operation in its specific case.

*This is what the code for my percent button looks like:*

```
If txtDisplay.Text.Length <> 0 Then
      If Operation = String.Empty Then
          Num1 = CType(txtDisplay.Text, Double)
          txtDisplay.Text = "0"
      Else CalculateTotals()
      End If
      Operation = "Percent"
      Point = False
End If
```

*This is what my calculation function looks like (excluding all other calculations):*

```
Function CalculateTotals()
    Num2 = CType(txtDisplay.Text, Double)
    Select Case Operation
            Case "Percent"
            Num1 /= 100 * Num2 & " %"
    End Select
    txtDisplay.Text = CType(Num1, String)
    Point = False
End Function
```

This will return the error "*Conversion from string "10000 %" to type 'Double' is not valid.*"

If anyone could suggest a possible solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change it around a little but I found an answer myself by just coding it to the percentage button itself.

```
Private Sub Percent(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPercent.Click
    '##########################
    '# Percent
    '##########################
    'Percentage calculation, example: 500 * 10% = 50
    Num2 = CType(txtDisplay.Text, Double)
    txtDisplay.Text = Val(Num1 * (Num2 / 100))
End Sub
```